# Opacity of layer's shadow

Tags: iphone, uiview, shadow, quartz-core

I add shadow to the UIView:

```
[blurView.layer setCornerRadius:kCornerRadius];    
blurView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
blurView.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
blurView.layer.backgroundColor = blurView.layer.shadowColor;
blurView.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath
                             bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(-2.0*kCornerRadius, -2.0*kCornerRadius, blurView.bounds.size.width+4.0*kCornerRadius, blurView.bounds.size.height+4.0*kCornerRadius)
                             cornerRadius:kCornerRadius].CGPath;
blurView.layer.cornerRadius = kCornerRadius;
blurView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0);
blurView.layer.shadowRadius = kCornerRadius;
blurView.layer.shadowOpacity = kOpacity;
blurView.layer.opacity = 1.0;
```

This part of code gives me a this view, like a uiview is blured:

[image]

When I try change opacity of blurView.layer (for example to 0.5), I get unexpected view:

[image]

As you can see - I get a sharp edges of uiview.

I think, shadow opacity is a part of opacity of layer - it's a cause of this 'error'. Can anybody help me to fix this? May be can I merge layers before change opacity of blurView.layer or something like this?

**UPD**

With this fix:
    blurView.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5] CGColor];

I get this:

[image]

**UPD**

Answer is using setShouldRasterize method:

[image]

Thanks everybody!

```
[blurView.layer setShouldRasterize:YES];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is using this code line:

```
blurView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try putting this in?

```
blurView.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5] CGColor];
```

Comment: With this line color densities of shadow and view box were similar, but it's not perfect. My goal is a effect like in a Photoshop with outer glow and layer opacity. Unfortunately, I can't use any image - only programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you put this :

```
blurView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
blurView.layer.opacity = 0.5;
```

I think that you might be setting the shadow opacity to 0.5 and then the whole layer to 0.5, making the shadow twice as transparent?

(or I'm completely wrong!)

Comment: Decreasing layer opacity decreases layer shadow opacity. And start shadow color and opacity are not equal main color, and opacity.

Comment: Maybe the shadow is visible through the view? Is this the reason for the difference in color?

Comment: I find answer: [blurView.layer setShouldRasterize:YES];

Comment: If that's the answer, why not answer the question yourself ;)